# OneNote notes lost?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, windows-11

Is oneNote 'pro' discontinued? It does not (seem to) come with the office package anymore. I ran the installer several times and it did not install it. Also, the logo does not show up in the list of what will be installed by the installer:

[image]

Whatever the answer, I wonder how to recover my notebooks.

I contacted Office support and they did not seem to be aware of any issue, all they told was to uninstall and reinstall, and maybe reboot.

Edit: Daniel B's answer works to install oneNote. However for some reason, it seems bad at finding cloud saved notebooks.

Basically, on this same PC, just another windows install (win 10 later upgraded to win 11), I just installed Office, got OneNote and it found my old notebooks from there, which are different than those from OneNote for Windows 10.

Comment: No. One Note has not been discontinued.  Look in One Note, History to see if your data is in the Recycle Bin. Look in other active Notebooks to see if you switched Notebooks inadvertently .  With respect to your later edit, uninstall Office, restart, reinstall Office, download One Note (take care 32bit or 64bit) and install that. Office does not appear to install One Note (desktop) by default.

Comment: @John Read this, “I ran the installer several times and it did not install it. Also, the logo does not show up in the list of what will be installed by the installer.”

Comment: If the OS install is fairly recent and the Office Install is new, then One Note is not installed by default. Users need to go to Microsoft and download One Note separately and install. Running the Office Installer will not fix this. The method changed only a short while back. My comment above is basically correct.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not discontinued (not yet, anyway). It has not been updated beyond its 2016 version, which no longer “fits” the current Office (dubbed Office 2019). So Microsoft decided at some point to exclude it. Later, it was apparently superficially updated and included again.

You can find this information [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/install-or-reinstall-onenote-for-windows-c08068d8-b517-4464-9ff2-132cb9c45c08). On this page, you will also find a download link for an updated version of the Office 365 installer.

I have Office 365 on my PC and it came with OneNote.

Comment: Note that Microsoft is trying to push everyone to use the MS Store version of OneNote, which is the dumbed-down version they are currently maintaining. unfortunately, MS decided to redesign OneNote to compete with mobile notes apps like evernote, rather than the more complex version which works best on a PC.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft will continue mainstream support for OneNote 2016 beyond October 2020, and its new support dates align with Office 2019 (October 10, 2023 for mainstream support and October 14, 2025 for extended support).

Starting in March 2020, when you install Office 365 or Office 2019, the OneNote desktop app will be installed alongside the Word, PowerPoint, and Excel desktop apps.

You could also [download OneNote 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/install-or-reinstall-onenote-2016-for-windows-c08068d8-b517-4464-9ff2-132cb9c45c08) and install it alone now.

For more, please refer to [Your OneNote](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365-Blog/Your-OneNote/ba-p/954922).